# Is it correct to use "studying the lessons"?

Tags: word-usage

I found a sentence in the book "Military Review". Is it correct to use the phrase *studying the lessons* in the following sentence?

> However, US analysts are not *studying the lessons* the Iraqis are learning from their Gulf War defeat.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't right?? Also, have you tried google? It's very common.

Comment: According to the 'Longman Dictionary of Common Errors', it isn't right, I think.

Comment: @thein lwin: If you have that impression, *please* give us a link to whatever Longman says that makes you think so. The problem must lie in how you've interpreted what Longman says, not in the example you've cited.

Answer (score 2):

In politics or even every day life, one hears: "What lessons or lesson did you learn from your experience as a [profession]?

This is a common image. In military speak or lingo, military people study what happens on and off to battlefield in military situations to incorporate those "lessons" into their future strategies or tactics.

One of the lessons I have learned in online forums is that one must take great care in being specific so one is  not misunderstood.

I hope my children will study these lessons when I share this knowledge with them.

In sum, to study lessons is a standard expression.

Studying the lessons the American failed to learn in Vietnam can be a painful experiences. They just seem to repeat themselves over and over and show they have not learned any lessons from their defeat.

Comment: There is also the stock phrase "lessons learned", as in [Joint Analysis and Lessons Learned Centre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Analysis_and_Lessons_Learned_Centre) or [U.S. Army Center for Army Lessons Learned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Army_Center_for_Army_Lessons_Learned).

Comment: @ColleenV Yes, the "stock phrase" comes from the idea of learning a lesson.